# Статический массив int'ов с не-const размером

Tags: char, c, массивы, gcc

В общем, имеется код. В функцию передается переменная need_size. Далее создается строка размером need_size. И тут загвоздка. Насколько я знаю, по стандарту языка Си, размер статических массивов должен быть известен на этапе компилляции. Однако, gcc версии 3 и 4 компиллируют сие чудо без нареканий (даже без ворнингов), visual c - сразу кидает три ошибки, одна их них - expected constant expression, что выглядит логично. Код, скомпиллированный gcc работает корректно. Подскажите, gcc заменяет такой код вызовом malloc? Или это магия Хогвартса и ничего не выделяется и при таком использовании есть риск выйти за пределы памяти?

```
char* string_space(char *str, int need_size)
{
char stringspace[need_size];
...
}
```

Comment: @Богдан Бессонов Вам уже ответили, так что замечание только по вопросу. Термин "статический массив" несколько сбивает с толку, поскольку для static массивов даже gcc не допускает переменных в описании длины -- только для automatic.

Comment: статический массив в моём понимании - массив, память для которого выделяется статически на этапе компиляции. Спасибо за замечание

Comment: Ну тут 

     память для которого выделяется статически на этапе компиляции

тоже моменты. Одно дело automatic, для которых память в языках с блоковой структурой, как нашёл дедушка Дейкстра, можно выделять (и выделяют) в стеке, и единственное, чем мешают массивы с переменными границами -- вычисление смещения во фреймах этого стека, и другое -- static, когда память выделяется на этапе компиляции и линковки, и иной размер массива означает пересборку исполняемого файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это нестандартное расширение GCC.

Ссылка на документацию: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length

Память таки выделяется в стеке, используя [`alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html). И да, если вы потребуете слишком много памяти, вы можете получить stack overflow.

---

Дополнение: если мы говорим о чистом C, автоматические массивы переменной длины являются частью языка, начиная со стандарта C99. MSVC, однако, включает поддержку новых стандартов C крайне медленно. При том, у них отличная поддержка стандартов C++. (Стандарт C++ не включает массивов переменной длины, так что C++ более не надмножество C.)

Comment: @Богдан Бессонов: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Про кресты - знаю. Вообще, это часть лабораторной в университете одного моего друга, там преподается Си в рамках С89. Впрочем, как и мне преподавался. Потому я и смотрю, что это за ерунда такая )